# How defile CSS rule path for iframe in cascade style sheet (CSS)?

Tags: css, iframe

I have a html page and i insert a iframe in this page. 
I have a problem with iframe contants.  In iframe show a button which have link to go on website anywhere, i want to that button does not show how set in CSS 
{display: none}
but how in iframe button no detect any css rule for displaying none.

Help me CSS MASTERS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`seamless`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) attribute:

> This Boolean attribute indicates that the browser should render the
>   inline frame in a way that makes it appear to be part of the
>   containing document, for example by **applying CSS styles** that apply to
>   the `<iframe>` to the contained document before styles specified in that
>   document, and by opening links in the contained documents in the
>   parent browsing context (unless another setting prevents this). In
>   XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the seamless attribute
>   must be defined as `<iframe seamless="seamless">`.

The problem is that browser support is currently negligible. Meanwhile, you can watch [Seamless iframes. The future, today!](http://benvinegar.github.io/seamless-talk/), a slideshow which can give you some ideas of how to implement those functionalities.

Comment: If i shall give a document link tomarow can dear you solve my problem. I shall full describe my problem there in text massage that actually what is really to do ! I hope this a game of you left hand.

Comment: it's not part of the standard yet and as such is not implemented in browsers except for chrome and safari (limited support on both)